Does Genesis contradicts the Big Bang theory about the time?
Although the Big Bang theory may be (like all scientific theories) subject to revision and improvement as new data becomes available, it is a robust scientific theory that is supported by a vast array of observational and experimental evidence. .
The Bible says that the Earth was created before the sun and the stars: In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth. ...this was the first day Gen.1:1 (I selected the part that interested me.)
And God said, “Let there be lights in the vault of the sky to separate the day from the night, and let them serve as signs to mark sacred times, and days and years, 15 and let them be lights in the vault of the sky to give light on the earth.” And it was so. 16 God made two great lights—the greater light to govern the day and the lesser light to govern the night. He also made the stars. 17 God set them in the vault of the sky to give light on the earth, 18 to govern the day and the night, and to separate light from darkness. And God saw that it was good. 19 And there was evening, and there was morning—the fourth day. Gen.1:14-19 (NIV)
However, we know according to the Big Bang theory that the birth of the first stars (called "population III stars) dates back to 13.6 billion years ago and that the Earth is 4.54 billion years old. It is true that there have been several types of light, for example the sun is 4.6 billion years old but starlight only appeared a few million years after the big bang.
So this contradicts science because in the Bible the Earth is created before light but the big bang theory says the opposite and this raises questions: Was the Bible wrong, therefore it is not the word of God ? Where is the interpretation of this text from Genesis to be taken metaphorically? If yes then where should we stop? Are we to believe that Adam and Eve are also some kind of metaphors?
(Personally I don't think so, I have always had a factual interpretation of Genesis. For me 1 day was equal to one day according to the Jewish calendar: the day begins at 06:00 then ends at 18:00 then at 06 :00 etc... My pastor told me this (principle of authority, it's funny), I would like to have your expert opinion on this.)

I am not an expert physicist (I doubt that anyone is, the way theories abound and fall out of fashion with such rapidity) nor is 'theoretical physics', itself, the study of absolute truth but rather the knowledge of current theories . But I think we have already covered this question elsewhere Age of Universe . . .  and . . . light.


The Big Bang theory [...] is a robust scientific theory that is supported by a vast array of observational and experimental evidence

It really isn't. Have you looked at the various extremely ad hoc adjustments that are made to force it to fit observations? What about those observations (e.g. the "horizon problem") that don't support it?
The theory that all planetary bodies "revolve" around the Earth through a set of epicycles is "supported by a vast array of observational and experimental evidence". It's also a terrible theory, but it's a good example of how a theory whose underlying premise is completely wrong can, with sufficient bludgeoning, be made to fit just about any evidence.

[...] we know according to the Big Bang theory [...]

Again, wrong. We know, according to Genesis, that the Earth was created before the sun and the stars. Scripture-denying scoffers assert that "the birth of the first stars dates back to 13.6 billion years ago and that the Earth is 4.54 billion years old". (Incidentally, JWST is busy poking holes in the first part of this assertion.)
There are also many, many problems with the claim that Earth is billions of years old, which have been discussed on this SE many times. Here are a few of those problems. What we actually know consists of only two circumstantial lines of evidence:

Stars are very far away (millions to billions of light-years) but we see their light.
Much radioactive decay has happened.

There are other proposed models to explain why we can see "distant" stars that don't require the Earth to be billions of years old. Similarly, while radioactive decay implies the passage of time, not only are alternate explanations possible, there is specific positive evidence that decay occurred in some cases very rapidly. Combined with many other lines of evidence, the natural conclusion is that Earth is a few thousand years old... exactly as recorded in Scripture.
However, if this is the case, why do so many people believe otherwise? Again, Scripture gives us the answers; we are sinful beings rightly deserving of God's Judgment. That's a scary thought, and one many people will do anything to deny. Scripture also predicts such denial (2 Peter 3:1-6; Romans 1:18-32) and further teaches that God Himself confuses the logic of those who hate the Truth (2 Thessalonians 2:9-12). Those who hate God cling desperately to their ideas of "long ages", because without so much time, the conclusion that life was Designed is irresistible. (Similarly, there is much evidence, even allowing for 'long ages', that "Common Descent" is false and that life was Designed; again, exactly as stated in Scripture. And again, those who hate God are desperate to embrace the "Common Descent" lie.)
So...

Does Genesis contradicts the Big Bang theory about the time?

Yes, it does. Because the latter is wrong.

Where is the interpretation of this text from Genesis to be taken metaphorically?

This is a difficult question, and the usual answer is that metaphors are naturally recognized. (Especially when they are linguistically metaphors, i.e. "X is like Y".) Earth doesn't have four literal "corners", nor does it sit on literal pillars, or the sea have literal barred doors. Genesis 1 is notably devoid of such. (The "expanse" is a bit of an issue, but not because it's a metaphor, but because it's a word that we don't know how to properly translate. It also may have multiple meanings, such as how "earth" can refer to the planet, to dry land, or to a handful of dirt.) However, some things that seem like metaphors — the "garment" or "curtains" of Creation (that is, the universe) or the "windows of Heaven" — have been theorized to be not so metaphorical after all. Spacetime is often described as a "fabric" that can be "spread out" and deformed.
In general, however, most people will agree on whether the "natural meaning" of a passage is intended to be literal or metaphorical. God is able to communicate effectively despite barriers of time, culture and language. Problems arise when people insist on using "science" to assign less natural interpretations. These attempts are often wrong, and in some cases science has even (eventually) vindicated something that Scripture has said all along.

Up-voted +1 (cancelling the down-vote) for a very balanced and sensible approach.

I'd be hesitant to say: We know, according to Genesis, that the Earth was created before the sun The Genesis account does not go into great detail. v2 ...darkness was over the surface of the deep does not specify why that was, was it cloud cover, was the planet created somewhere before brought into the solar system, was the sun not created, were the physics not applied yet, or something else.

@depperm, that's blatant eisegesis, and exactly my point. No one simply reading Scripture would conclude other than that the "greater and lesser lights" were Created on Day 4. Additionally, this order is only one of many irreconcilable differences between Scripture and the Materialist "creation" story; even if one were to twist that particular pretzel into Scripture, it's nowhere near sufficient to make the two accounts match up.

@Matthew might be eisegesis, but the same can be said about anyone's reading. The book was written a long time ago. The bible is not a science book. My whole point is claiming we know something from minimal scripture reference isn't a good foundation.

@depperm, and my point is that you're denying God's ability to inspire the authors of Scripture to write in a way that is comprehensible without "special knowledge". That is the Gnosticism heresy. The focus of Scripture is not "science", true, but where it makes claims that have scientific implications, those claims are true. Otherwise you throw out inerrancy, and then you have the OP's problem... where do we stop? If you're going to consistently place "science" above Scripture, then you must assert that Jesus wasn't resurrected. Anything in between is incoherent.

not being able to explain the science does not mean I deny that it happened. Even with science there are multiple ways it could have been done, like I initially mentioned.
